# Подскажите как сделать иконку в приложении на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, windowicon

Надо поменять эту иконку в Pyqt5. Подскажите, как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QSize


class Ui_Form(object):
  def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Расчет синтезатора частот")
    Form.setFixedSize(408, 1300)
    #Form.resize(408, 1300)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 341, 30))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 60, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 391, 1190))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 20))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(163, 10, 131, 20))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 90, 22))
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "РСЧ"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Расчет по формулам"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "1"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "2"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "3"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "4"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "5"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "6"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "7"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Form", "8"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Form", "9"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Form", "10"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Form", "11"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Form", "12"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("Form", "13"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(13, _translate("Form", "14"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(14, _translate("Form", "15"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(15, _translate("Form", "16"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(16, _translate("Form", "17"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(17, _translate("Form", "18"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(18, _translate("Form", "19"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(19, _translate("Form", "20"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(20, _translate("Form", "21"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(21, _translate("Form", "22"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(22, _translate("Form", "23"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(23, _translate("Form", "24"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(24, _translate("Form", "25"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Вариант:"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Параметры МБТ:"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "KT331"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "KT3104"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "KT366B"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "KT306"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "KT311E"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "KT603A"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "KT617A"))
```

[image: Надо поменять эту иконку в Pyqt5]

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, ваш пример и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Не выложился скриншот. Когда открываю форму , сверху есть иконка рядом с названием самого файла, как его исправить на свою иконку

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Исправил и добавил пример кода

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-icon-to-a-window-in-pyqt5/

Answer (score 1):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> windowIcon : QIcon
>
> Это свойство содержит значок виджета
>
> Это свойство имеет смысл только для окон. Если значок не был установлен, windowIcon() возвращает значок приложения (QApplication::windowIcon()).
>
> Примечание. В macOS значки окон представляют активный документ и не будут отображаться, если путь к файлу также не был установлен с помощью setWindowFilePath.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QSize


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Расчет синтезатора частот")
        Form.setFixedSize(408, 1300)
        #Form.resize(408, 1300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 341, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 60, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 391, 1190))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(163, 10, 131, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 90, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "РСЧ"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Расчет по формулам"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "7"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Form", "8"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Form", "9"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Form", "10"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Form", "11"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Form", "12"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("Form", "13"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(13, _translate("Form", "14"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(14, _translate("Form", "15"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(15, _translate("Form", "16"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(16, _translate("Form", "17"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(17, _translate("Form", "18"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(18, _translate("Form", "19"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(19, _translate("Form", "20"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(20, _translate("Form", "21"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(21, _translate("Form", "22"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(22, _translate("Form", "23"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(23, _translate("Form", "24"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(24, _translate("Form", "25"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Вариант:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Параметры МБТ:"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "KT331"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "KT3104"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "KT366B"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "KT306"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "KT311E"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "KT603A"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "KT617A"))
    

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Ok.png"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]